# How should I load images for devices with different pixel ratios?

Tags: html, css, image

I've just learned that devices can have pixel ratios (number of hardware pixels in a CSS pixel).

I've been told, when doing media queries, for a device with a pixel ratio of 2 that claims 750x1334, we really have to treat it as 375x667. If we just plan for the eventuality of any viewport size surely there’s no additional complication here?

Comment: One strategy to consider is not to use pixels at all.  I can't remember the last time I did a layout via pixels.  I usually use `em`s, as by default `1em` is a readable font size on every device.  I scale everything from there.  For example, if I'm layout out text, I might have a `max-width` of `60em`, as that's pretty reasonable for a line length.  But, I won't specify the width... I'll let the device flow it so that if it's a vertically held cell phone, there might only be `20em` of width... but the device can decide.

Comment: Depends on how important the images are to your users. As a photographer (which I am) I would want crisp, clear and full sized images I can zoom into, as a whatsapp user I couldn't care less. There is no real rule of thumb, but I would use 1x or 2x the size of the targeted devices' software pixels, ignoring the hardware DPI. (I'm sure someone will x me for saying this, especially a pp-person: pixel-perfect, that is...). And what @Brad said!

Comment: This extends to other things too.  Header might be `4em` tall.  Buttons might have `1em` of padding.  It all works pretty well.

Comment: And beware not to get drawn into the whole PPI/DPI/SP/DP calculations and @media construction. It is a snake-pit with little consensus on what the best strategy would be. Moreover, each year dozens of new devices with new ratios hit the market. You do the math. Even Google can't figure this out properly with their 'material Design' (version 7+ or something). Be smart and go for some 'average looks good' version and let the big guys (with the big bucks) figure out what's best.

Comment: Final remark: I'm not ranting over Google, I do like Android, 'Material Design' and 'Google Web Components', but soft- vs. hardware pixels has been an ongoing issue ever since their 'web starter-kit' and 'Web Fundamentals' (before 2015, I believe, MD and GWC predecessors). So don't expect a proper solution any time soon.

Comment: Why is it common to use em? It's not like it's scaleable i.e. if rem is 16px, and you set a div height to 10rem, it's not going to scale down as the viewport gets smaller

Comment: Using a meta `viewport`, and `rem`,  and percentages, and @media breakpoints will always work. The rem is related to the root, percentages can be used for the structure, images and some other things. Useful breakpoints are already given by Bootstrap. With these you don't have to bother about all those pixel sizes and pixel ratios.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RenevanderLende. Would you say my points in my question are true - that I can effectively ignore whatever is meant by pixel ratio and just plan websites according to viewport width using DevTools?

Comment: I tend to ignore hardware pixels as they seem to matter only when you need high graphic accuracy like in 3D graphics, math or photography. So yes, go for the easy option first. You can always go the extra mile when things don't pan out as expected...

Comment: @bron `Using a meta `viewport`  - what did you mean by that? :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right, here's what you can do to load images based on 1x,2x pixel ratio

```html
<img srcset="small.jpg 1x, large.jpg 2x" src="small.jpg" alt="A rad wolf" />
```

The `srcset` attribute takes a comma-separated list of image URLs, each with an `x` descriptor stating the `device-pixel-ratio`

Comment: Thanks Zain. My question is, what does specifying for different resolution sizes really achieve? At the end of the day can’t everything be looked at in terms of CSS pixels. So just use stuff like this?:

`<picture>
  <source media=“(max-width: 500px)” srcset=“small.jpg”>
  <img src=“large.jpg” alt=“me”>
</picture>`

Comment: Also, does this code have to do with anything?
`<meta name=“viewport” content=“width=device-width, initial-scale=1”>`

Comment: 1. Yes everything can be looked in terms of CSS pixels but the problem is that if you want to leave it upto the browser to load appropriate size image based on css pixels you can use 1x 2x etc. But if you have more breakpoints to cater and custom breakpoints to handle you need to specify exact width according to the use case.

Comment: 2. As as viewport is concerned, when you load a 980px website on an iphone of 320px it would assume that you are trying to load webpage who's width is 980px and would try to fit in the content thus zooming it out. So one way of handling it would be use `content="width=320"` though it works for 320px phone but isn't very generic to make it generic we go with `content="width=device-width"` which will be calculated based on device width and additionally to set the zoom level to 1 by default we specify the initial scale level